# if statement checking regex expression not working

Tags: shell

I have start learning shell programming today, what I am trying out is to do a simple option menu with 3 choices and if the user key in 1,2 or 3, it will be a valid input. anything besides 1,2,3 will be a invalid input.I have tried it out but it's not working as in nothing happened with my codes below. 
Please advice thanks.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while  :
 do

    clear

       #display menu
       echo "1) choice 1"
       echo "2) choice 2"
       echo "3) choice 3"
       read -p "Enter choice: " choice
       regex = "[1-3]"
       if  [[ $choice -ne $regex ]]; then
           echo "Invalid input"
       else
           case $choice in 
           1) echo "this is choice one"
           2) echo "this is choice two"
           3) echo "this is choice three"
esac
     fi
done
```

Comment: You are reimplementing the `select` command, which handles displaying the menu and matching input to a menu item for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `clear` or you won't see anything.

### Errors

Remove the blanks around `=`:

```
regex="[1-3]"
```

Your cases must end with `;;`:

```
1) echo "this is choice one";;
2) echo "this is choice two";;
3) echo "this is choice three";;
```

### Suggestions

Introduce an exit case:

```
'x') exit 0;;
```

The test `[[ ]]` is not needed if you use a default case as the last case:

```
*) echo "invalid input";;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing it as a *regex*.  Say:

```
if [[ ! $choice =~ $regex ]]; then
```

Moreover, you shouldn't put spaces are `=` during assignment.  Say:

```
regex="[1-3]"
```

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> An additional binary operator, `‘=~’`, is available, with the same
>   precedence as `‘==’` and `‘!=’`. When it is used, the string to the right
>   of the operator is considered an **extended regular expression** and
>   matched accordingly